# Is there any way to run a TFS query using a `QueryItem`?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm retrieving the queries using `teamProject.QueryHierarchy`.

It is working, I can see its details of this query like Name, ID, Path, but no WIQL string, so I can't use that `QueryItem` to execute a query on TFS.

Is there any way to run a query using this `QueryItem`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone look up for this too, I solved my problem this way:

```
QueryDefinition q = queryItem as QueryDefinition;

string wiql = q.QueryText;
```